# How to get data from JSP to Action class by id instead of property in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am doing on Java Struts 2 framework.

Normally, I can get data from my JSP through the get set method in `Form.java` (action class). Below is my example :

In `main.jsp` file:

```
<html:text property="campaignName" size="50" maxlength="50" />
```

thus, I can get this text box name by get set method in the action class, the below is code from

**`mainForm.java` :**

```
private String campaignName = null;

public String getCampaignName() {
    return campaignName;
}

public void setCampaignName(String campaignName) {
    this.campaignName = campaignName;
}
```

However, because of I want to use jQuery to do something, I no longer use `<html:text>` as text box, but I use `<input type="text" id="datepicker" />`.

Because of without property attribute inside this text box, I cant get the value from this text box. I have tried to add `property="something"` inside the text box also, but get set method in `mainForm.java` is return `null`.

I would like to ask, how can I get the value by this text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:textfield name="campaignName" size="50" maxlength="50" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="campaignName" size="50" maxlength="50" />
```

The name need to be matched with the field name

Comment: Hi PSR, ya, I use `<input type="text" name="campaignName" size="50" maxlength="50" />` , it is working fine to display the text box in web page, my problem is, how can I get this text box value from action class? my action class in my question is mainForm.java.

Comment: You can use getCampaignName() to get the value

Answer (score 1):

The simple usage of that textbox is to use `s:textfield` tag.

```
<s:textfield name="campaignName" size="50" maxlength="50" />
```

Comment: Hi Roman C, do I need to include something inside the jsp? Because I use your code in my jsp, but when I browser it, the text field is not appear.

Comment: @PanadolChong Include JSP taglib definition to make struts tags available in the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<s:textfield name="campaignName" size="50" maxlength="50" />`  and add struts tag to your jsp ( at the top ):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```